# Enum with associated value as stored property in Swift extension

Tags: swift, enum, extension-methods, properties

I have a service which connects to server using socket and stays connected,
I used this enum to manage connection state:

```
enum ConnectionState {
  case none, connecting, failed(Error), connected, disconnected(Error), blocked
}
```

I wanted to have `connectionState` as property to know current connection state of service but in extension of service provider class.

Why in extension and not in class itself?
Because `ServiceProvider` class is not Swift class, its **ObjC class** and there is no way we I can declare `ConnectionState` swift enum with associated values in ObjC class.

So I used associative stored property in swift extension, but as `ConnectionState` has associated values I need to do little more.

First I created extension to enum to make dictionary convertible as:

```
extension ConnectionState {
  var dictPresentation: [String: Error?] {
    switch self {
    case .none: return ["none": nil]
    case .connecting: return ["connecting": nil]
    case .failed(let error): return ["failed": error]
    case .connected: return ["connected": nil]
    case .disconnected(let error): return ["disconnected": error]
    case .blocked: return ["blocked": nil]
    }
  }

  init(dict: [String: Error?]) {
    assert(!dict.isEmpty, "dict must contain one key")
    let key = dict.keys.first!
    let error: Error? = dict[key] ?? nil
    switch key {
    case "none": self = .none
    case "connecting": self = .connecting
    case "failed": self = .failed(error!)
    case "connected": self = .connected
    case "disconnected": self = .disconnected(error!)
    case "blocked": self = .blocked
    default:
        assert(false, "wrong key in dict")
        self = .none
    }
  }
}
```

Then used it in service provider class extension as:

```
private var ConnectionStateHolderKey: UInt8 = 7
extension ServiceProvider {
  private var _connectionStateHolder: NSDictionary {
    get {
        if let connectionStateDict = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &ConnectionStateHolderKey) as? NSDictionary {
            return connectionStateDict
        }
        //return ["none": nil] gives error "nil is not compatible with expected dictionary value type 'Any'"
        //return ["none": nil as Any] gifs error "Nil is not compatible with 'Any' in coercion"

        let dict = NSDictionary()
        dict.setValue(nil, forKey: "none")
        return dict//default state = none
    }
    set {
        objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &ConnectionStateHolderKey, newValue, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
    }
  }

  var connectionState: ConnectionState {
    get {
        return ConnectionState(dict: _connectionStateHolder as! [String : Error?])
    }
    set {
      _connectionStateHolder = newValue.dictPresentation as NSDictionary
    }
  }
}
```

Is there anything that can be used to simplify this code and avoid dictionary conversion?
Any suggestions that can improve this code are welcomed!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First note that your `var connectionState` is  *computed* property,
not a stored property. It is computed using the `get` and `set`
methods. Extensions cannot add stored properties to a type.

Your current implementation crashes if the connection state is retrieved
without having been set before:

```
let provider = ServiceProvider()
print(provider.connectionState)
```

because at

```
let dict = NSDictionary()
dict.setValue(nil, forKey: "none")
```

`dict` is an *immutable* dictionary. Making it mutable does not solve the
problem

```
let dict = NSMutableDictionary()
dict.setValue(nil, forKey: "none")
```

because the second statement has no effect and therefore the assertion

```
assert(!dict.isEmpty, "dict must contain one key")
```

fails.

You want to create a `NSDictionary` which – when bridged to `[String: Error?]` – becomes `["none": nil]`. The difficulty here is that the
value type of the Swift dictionary is an optional. But it is possible,
using `NSNull()`:

```
    get {
        if let connectionStateDict = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &ConnectionStateHolderKey) as? NSDictionary {
            return connectionStateDict
        }
        return ["none": NSNull()]
    }
```

(compare [SE-0140 Warn when Optional converts to Any, and bridge Optional As Its Payload Or NSNull](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0140-bridge-optional-to-nsnull.md)).

**But:** All these conversions between `enum`, Swift dictionary and `NSDictionary`
are actually not needed, you can achieve the same much simpler.

As stated in [Swift Blog: Objective-C id as Swift Any](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=39),

> The Objective-C bridge in Swift 3 can in turn present any Swift value as an id-compatible object to Objective-C.

This means that you can pass an `enum ConnectionState` directly to `objc_setAssociatedObject()`
and conditionally cast the return value from `objc_getAssociatedObject()` back to the enum.
The Swift runtime automatically wraps the value into a class.
([AnyObject not working in Xcode8 beta6?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39033194/1187415)
on Stack Overflow contains further information and links.)

So this is everything you need:

```
enum ConnectionState {
    case none, connecting, failed(Error), connected, disconnected(Error), blocked
}

private var ConnectionStateHolderKey: UInt8 = 7
extension ServiceProvider {

    var connectionState: ConnectionState {
        get {
            if let connectionState = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &ConnectionStateHolderKey) as? ConnectionState {
                return connectionState
            }
            return .none
        }
        set {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &ConnectionStateHolderKey, newValue, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
        }
    }
}
```

More suggestions:

- Use the nil-coalescing operator `??` to provide a default value in the getter method.
- Restrict the scope of the associated objects key by making it a static property inside `extension ServiceProvider`.

Then the code would look like this:

```
extension ServiceProvider {

    private struct Keys {
        static var connectionState : UInt8 = 7
    } 

    var connectionState: ConnectionState {
        get {
            return (objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &ServiceProvider.Keys.connectionState) as? ConnectionState) ?? .none
        }
        set {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &ServiceProvider.Keys.connectionState, newValue, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
        }
    }
}
```

Finally: Your enum has a case `none` for "no state". But the Swift way
of representing "no value" is to use an *optional:*

```
enum ConnectionState {
    case connecting, failed(Error), connected, disconnected(Error), blocked
}

extension ServiceProvider {

    private struct Keys {
        static var connectionState : Int = 0
    } 

    var connectionState: ConnectionState? {
        get {
            return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &ServiceProvider.Keys.connectionState) as? ConnectionState
        }
        set {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &ServiceProvider.Keys.connectionState, newValue, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I still wonder how `.failed(Error)` would be converted and stored if we directly save enum without converting to dictionary; testing this...

Comment: Can you please explain more on "Define the associated objects key locally"? I defined it `private`.

Comment: @D4ttatraya: Your `private var ConnectionStateHolderKey` is visible in the entire source file. My suggested `ServiceProvider.Keys.connectionState` is only visible inside the extension, i.e. the visibility is limited to the scope where the value is needed.

Answer (score 1):

My Suggestion: instead backporting Swift to objc better look forward to Swift

I would create a wrapping swift class/struct `ServiceConnection` witch has 2 properties:

- `serviceProvider`
- `connectionState`